# Why don't you... ---> Why don't we

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

It's known that a phrase *"Why don't you...?"* is used to make a suggestion. Is it possible to say the following with the same meaning:

> I’m afraid, I have no time now. **Why don’t we meet later?**

Or we can say only:

> I’m afraid, I have no time now. **Can we meet later?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, "I'm afraid I have no time now" shouldn't have a comma.

Yes. "Why don't we meet later?" can be used to make a suggestion. It's less terse than "Can we meet later?" Both are colloquial, but if you were speaking to your manager, "*Could* we meet later?" or even "Could we *possibly* meet later?" might be more acceptable. The latter is appropriate when speaking to someone you've [let down](https://www.lexico.com/definition/let_down).